# Is it possible to create a many-to-many relationship with two columns that contain duplicated values?

Tags: sql

I have two tables that I would like to create a relationship between them:

One is called `Products` and it contains data as such, the `id` is the the primary key:

```
id product_id name  env
1   1         Python prod
2   1         Python test
3   1         Python uat
4   2         Rusty  test
5   2         Rusty  prod
```

`Licence` table is like that, it has no primary key this table:

```
product_id name phase_type
1          Python Available
1          Python Extension
1          Python Obsolete
2          Rusty  Available
2          Rusty  Extension
2          Rusty  Obsolete
```

I would like to create a relationship between these two tables, however the `product_id` in table `Products` is duplicated and the same happens in table `Licence`. Is it possible to create at all a relationship between these tables ?

Comment: What is the PK for the second table?

Comment: You may create a Product table where Id is a PK and make both your tables refer it with a FK.

Comment: what is the expected result of join * from products P join license L on P.id = L.product_id where product_id = 1 ? you will get 9 rows this way...

Comment: @gimix it has no primary key

Comment: @Serg make both my tables refer with a foreign key ? Could you elaborate more on that ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data look like referencing the same set of, say, ProductTypes. You can create a table

```
ProductType
Id(PK) Name
1      Python
2      Rusty
```

and refactor your current tables excluding `Name` column

```
Product
id productType_id(FK to ProductType.Id) env
1   1                              prod
2   1                              test
3   1                              uat
4   2                              test
5   2                              prod

Licence 
productType_id(FK to ProductType.Id)  phase_type
1                                    Available
1                                    Extension
1                                    Obsolete
2                                    Available
2                                    Extension
2                                    Obsolete
```

Then you can combine above data in your queries at will, join on `productType_id` for example.